# Laravel GET http://www.website.com/css/style.css net::ERR_ABORTED

Tags: php, html, css, laravel, hyperlink

Ya'all are my last chance to somehow solve this issue that's been stalling me for the past 2 weeks and I have not managed to find an answer.

I have my website hosted on Hostinger with Laravel 5.1 installed.

I'm trying to link my css files from the public/css folder but I always get net::ERR_ABORTED error when it's trying to load the files.

My /public/.htaccess file is as follows:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ / [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(css|js|images)/(.*)$ public// [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

The one from the root is as follows

```
Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/ [L]

# Redirect Trailing Slashes...
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ / [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

RewriteRule ^(css|js|images)/(.*)$ public// [L,NC]
</IfModule>
```

I've tried linking the css files with all of these ways

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="{!! asset('/css/style.css') !!}">

<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('/css/style.css') }}">

<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="{!! asset('css/style.css') !!}">

<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/style.css') }}">

{!! Html::style('css/style.css') !!}

{!! Html::style('/css/style.css') !!}

<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">

<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
```

None has proved to work and I honestly see no other way to actually link and use the css files I have. I'm stuck on this and I'm actually desperate to find a way to make it work.

All of the css/js files are in /public/css/ or /public/js/

Help a coder out 'cuz I feel like just quitting this. I don't know if the .htaccess files are somehow restricting the acces or what is happening.

Cheers, G.

Comment: do the js files work? can you save laravel index.php in another folder .. and add a simple index.php in its place (for testing purposes) including pure html with the css linked and check the results?

Comment: access the direct link to the file in the browser and let me know if that works.

Comment: @HamzaMohamed results are the same, so the blade extension is not the problem

Comment: @Adamnick - I can't access the css files like that :) i'm getting the standard laravel "Page not found"

Comment: What is your pubic folder permissions?

Comment: drwxrwxrwx for the public folder - I did a chmod 777 -R on it to make sure it has all the rights.

Comment: can give extra information on how is laravel folders added? is it added to the public_html or are you using vps? which tutorial did you follow?

Comment: I'm using the normal hosting services, I used the website installer provided by Hostinger that installed Laravel 5.1.11 on the website. Yes, it is added to the public_html folder and the structure is the standard laravel one.

Comment: access like this website.com/public/css/style.css

Comment: @Adamnick Doesn't work - i get "Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found." for website.com/public/css/style.css and website.com/css/style.css

Comment: Remove `RewriteRule ^(css|js|images)/(.*)$ public// [L,NC]`.

Comment: @ako Same issue sadly :( this rule i've added recently after trying other things to see if the .htaccess file might be the problem (i don't know much about how it works)

Comment: Somehow i'm sure the problem is in `.htaccess` file, But don't know what part of it exactly, I had same issues with `.htaccess` file. Try to clear the content of `.htaccess` file in `public` folder and put the content suggested by laravel documentation for apache [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1#configuration) and remove `.htaccess` file in root of your project.

Comment: @ako I think so also, but it's not the case here... this change actually broke the site and I could no longer access it. I'm getting a blank view

Comment: U mean with this changes returning views does not work? Why site must break?

Comment: Yep :) I tried a fresh install of laravel with a basic public/css/style.css that changes the <p></p> to color red and the error persists. So i'm all out of ideas.

Comment: Restart your web server.

Comment: I have no idea how to do that on a shared web server, the website is hosted on Hostinger :) i don't think those guys would allow me to restart their webserver.

Comment: That's definitely .htaccess issue .. you would better check server fault or ask Ubuntu or Unix&Linux.. or even better get a vps for 2.5 @ vultr or $5 @ digital ocean .. or the best offer which is $10~12 @ SSD nodes